# write out a formula with paste

Tags: r, formula, paste

currently I have a piece of code that looks liek this

```
as.formula(paste0('Y~',paste('factor','(', names(te)[w],')', sep="",collapse="+")))
```

the response (Y) and the predictors TRY1,Y2,UYP21 and GHT9 are columnames of the dataframe te and w is a vector which indexes the column names as only specific columns from the data frame are chosen for the model.

My problem is that this code will write the formula for all predictors as factor(). How can i write a piece that will decide that for w=12 (12th column of te) it should be not factor but as.numeric. 
Even more general it should check the class of the data frame column with class() and then decide whether to use factor or as numeric. The desired output is

```
Y~factor(TRY1)+factor(TRY2)+factor(UYP21)+as.numeric(GHT9)
```

while the current code produces

```
Y~factor(TRY1)+factor(TRY2)+factor(UYP21)+factor(GHT9)
```

the answer provided works very well but the problem is that it really woudl net to be as.numeric not only numeri

Comment: You can use `sapply(y, class)` or `sapply(y, is.factor)` to find the class.

Comment: think that this is potentially a different problem as the only way this can be done si I suppose with some kind of if statement?....

Comment: @akrun thanks for the comment....i think i can determine the typ of a column but i dont know how I would implement the if factor paste as X and if numeric paste as Y bit. Any suggestions? Would be really grateful

Comment: It is better you show an example dataset just like the one I showed in your earlier post.  It will get you more responses.

Comment: My doubt is that if the `GHT9` is numeric, then why do you have to specify `as.numeric(GHT9)`

Comment: Maybe `do.call(paste(stuff))`

Comment: Can you explain your *actual* goal? Why do you want to do this in the first place?  There is probably a better way to go about the problem.

Comment: @Dason is right: more likely you can do this by calling a formula with the indices of the factors rather than their names (use a `list` variable to hold your data)

Comment: If your columns are a factor in the data.frame, you don't need to use `factor()` in the formula. Did you import them as character? If so, the "easeiest" fix would just be to convert your character columns to factor since that's how you want them to behave. Don't use the formula to fix your data problems; just fix your data.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best coding, but maybe it helps.

```
forFormula <- NULL
for(i in 1:dim(te)[2]){ 
  one <- paste0(class(te[,i]), "(", colnames(te)[i], ")")
  forFormula <- c(forFormula, one)
}
forFormula <- as.formula(paste("Y ~", (paste(forFormula, collapse="+"))))
```

Comment: hello...that works the only problem is that it would need to be as.numeric() not only numeric....could you cancege that maybe?